# PHP how to compare strings between two variables and display only unique strings?

Tags: php, string-comparison

**NOTE:** here in the S.O. **there are many ways to do this** with array keys, between values/words of the same variables, between two different arrays, but I see nothing on the internet between strings and not arrays of two different variables.

```
<?php
$a = 'this car is very beautiful and is the fast';
$b = 'this red car is very beautiful and is the fast that others';
var_export($unique_words = show_unique_strings($a, $b));
//expected output(painted on the screen): red that others
?>
```

Comment: You could `explode` your strings into arrays, do the array stuff and then `implode` the result. ;)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php You got arrays, again, anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Siphalor stated here is an implementation

```
$a = 'this car is very beautiful and is the fast';
$b = 'this red car is very beautiful and is the fast that others';
echo $unique_words = show_unique_strings($a, $b);
//expected output(painted on the screen): red that others

function show_unique_strings($a, $b) {
  $aArray = explode(" ",$a);
  $bArray = explode(" ",$b);
  $intersect = array_intersect($aArray, $bArray);
  return implode(" ", array_merge(array_diff($aArray, $intersect), array_diff($bArray, $intersect)));
}
```

Comment: the output is white, how does it print the expected output on the screen with this type of return?

Comment: sorry I had them in the wrong order you can try again now

Comment: Made it a more complete solution so you don't need to worry about the order of the strings

Comment: I need it to appear on the screen, on the page, an echo with the output of the unique string: `// expected output (painted on the screen): red that others`  so far I have not got it, I need to separate thousands of unique words, and it has no echo in that code, it does not print on the browser screen! I need to print this on the screen of a php site.

Comment: the print_r/echo/var_export should work on the result of this function

Comment: You shouldn't need to return the value just do this in your call to the function `echo show_unique_strings($a, $b)`

Comment: Not working neither outside nor inside the function `echo show_unique_strings($a, $b)` too var_dump, var_export, print_r etc...

Comment: I am pretty sure the method itself is working, you need figure out what is going wrong with your writing to the webpage. Can you write a echo hello world to it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161476/discussion-between-kartik-prasad-and-ariane-martins-gomes-do-rego).

Comment: I have updated the answer to give you exactly what you need in a plain .php file, copy and paste it to http://phpfiddle.org/ and you'll see the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$a = 'this car is very beautiful and is the fast';
$b = 'this red car is very beautiful and is the fast that others';

var_dump(getUniqWords($a, $b));

function getUniqWords($str1, $str2){
    $aWords = explode(" ", $str1);
    $bWords = explode(" ", $str2);
    $results[] = array();

    if(count($aWords) > count($bWords)){
        for($i=0;$i<count($aWords);$i++){
            if(!in_array($aWords[$i], $bWords)){
                array_push($results, $aWords[$i]);
            }
        }
    }else{
        for($i=0;$i<count($bWords);$i++){
            if(!in_array($bWords[$i], $aWords)){
                array_push($results, $bWords[$i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```